# Interdependence of modules in python packages

Tags: python, import, module, package, modulenotfounderror

I have created a package called 'pkg' and it looks like this:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

`mod1.py` contains only one function and looks like this.

```
# mod1.py

def my_sqrt(x):

    s = 5 # initialize at 5
    while abs(x - s**2) > 0.00001:
        s = (s+x/s)/2
    return s
```

`mod2.py` contains a function that uses the function `my_sqrt` from `mod1.py` and looks like this.

```
# mod2.py

def fourth_root(x):
    return my_sqrt(my_sqrt(x))
```

Now when I run

```
from pkg import *
my_sqrt(9)
```

I get output of `3.000000001396984` as desired but if I then run

```
fourth_root(81)
```

I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'`.
Even if I add the following line in `mod2.py`,

```
from mod1 import my_sqrt
```

It still doesn't work and throws the following error: `NameError: name 'my_sqrt' is not defined`.

Due to some logical structure, I want to define the functions `my_sqrt` and `fourth_root` in separate modules. How do I do that and not get an error. I am having a hard time understanding how to arrange my package so that these interdependence between modules are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Import all methods from mod1.py and mod2.py at pkg level.

**init**.py should look like below to achive what u want.

```
from mod1 import my_sqrt
from mod2 import fourth_root
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the methods from mod1.py and mod2.py in **init**.py

**init**.py should look like this.

```
from .mod1 import my_sqrt
from .mod2 import fourth_root
__all__ = [my_sqrt, fourth_root]
```

Comment: No. Still I get the same error `NameError: name 'my_sqrt' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

The code should run from inside pkg directory. But since you want to run it from outside, you have to mention its local path. Otherwise, when the main code (outside pkg) enters pkg/mod2.py, it starts finding mod1 module at its location level and can't find it.

"from .mod1 import my_sqrt" inside mod2 should work.
Adding the dot is key here.